# Lumen e Banco de Dados Firebird

Tags: laravel-eloquent, lumen

É possível utilizar o Lumen e o Eloquent em um banco de dados Firebird que já é utilizado por outra aplicação, sem que o ORM faça alterações na estrutura do banco de dados?

Outro detalhe: há possibilidade de acessar somente uns 10% das tabelas sem o risco de alteração, criando somente as classes Models necessárias?

Estou começando a aprender o framework e gostaria de saber desta possibilidade.

Teriam como indicar algum artigo, matéria ou livro que me auxiliasse para tal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> É possível utilizar o Lumen e o Eloquent em um banco de dados Firebird
>   que já é utilizado por outra aplicação, sem que o ORM faça alterações
>   na estrutura do banco de dados?

Sim, é possível. O Eloquent não altera a estrutura de tabelas do banco de origem (exceto os casos que você crie uma *migration*). Você só precisa adaptar o Model, como o campo de *primary key*, nome da tabela, acessar os campos corretos, e por ai vai.

A [Documentação do Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent) te mostra como fazer isso.

Para o suporte do Firebird com o Lumen ou Laravel, você pode utilizar esse *package*:

https://github.com/jacquestvanzuydam/laravel-firebird/tree/5.2-sup

> Outro detalhe: há possibilidade de acessar somente uns 10% das tabelas
>   sem o risco de alteração, criando somente as classes Models
>   necessárias?

Somente os Models que você implementar vão poder manipular as tabelas. O que você não implementar se não for necessário vai ficar de fora.

> Teriam como indicar algum artigo, matéria ou livro que me auxiliasse
>   para tal?

Você pode optar por ler a documentação do Lumen, do Laravel ou do *package* que recomendei para isso. Pra você que está começando não sei se é uma boa ideia ir direto pelo Lumen, pois você vai ter que fazer muita coisa na mão.

Um passo a passo para o que você quer fazer dificilmente você irá encontrar, mas nada impede que você quebre um pouco a cabeça e publique algo que possa ajudar alguém no futuro :)

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção a resposta. Bem completa e me deu um norte para minha solução. Vou estudar bem a solução proposta e vou considerar seu conselho sobre o Lumen.